# How to deploy a symfony 3 app with Capifony?

Tags: php, capistrano, symfony, capifony

My problem is that I can't use capifony correctly with my project on the Symfony 3. After  installing composer dependencies I get an error with running app/console commands and rollback of deploy.

I know that in symfony 3 app/console moved to bin/console. But how I can change in Capifony?

Thanks!

Comment: I know you already have an answer, but for posterity can you post the error message you mentioned?

Comment: @amphetamachine, At the moment I can't show the text of the error message i got, because it's all ok now, but I can explain the error in my own words. So, after the composer components were installed, capifony tried to clear the cache. It tried to run bash commands 'app/console cache:clear --env=dev' and 'app/console cache:clear --env=dev' and failed because it can't find file app/console. That's all. After that I got the rollback of my deploy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capifony is no longer maintained, so it doesn't evolves depending on Symfony releases.

> Capifony is based on Capistrano v2.x and will stick to this version (i.e. Capifony is feature-frozen, and will only accept bug fixes).
>
> At the time of writing, Capistrano v3 is the current major version, and Capifony is not compatible with it.
>
> Don't worry, there is a plugin for that! Using Capistrano v3 + capistrano/symfony (heavily inspired by Capifony) may be the way to go for new projects! You can read more on capifony and its future.

From [here](https://github.com/everzet/capifony).

Plus, from the first lines of the [capifony website](http://capifony.org/):

> capifony is a deployment recipes collection that works with both symfony and Symfony2 applications.

So, don't work with symfony3 and will not go in this way.

I know it's a bit hard to migrate, but you should really change your deployment workflow to [Capistrano with its symfony tasks](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony).

Then you'll be able to configure the console path:

```
set :symfony_console_path, "bin/console"
```

I suspect that you can use it in Capifony, you should try it before upgrading.

**Note** You'll have other problems related to the Symfony3 architecture, such as the `cache` and `logs` directory. See all [available configurations](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony#settings).

Comment: _Capifony is deprecated_ - but I can't find any information about its deprecation.

Comment: See the first paragraph of the [README](https://github.com/everzet/capifony) . Capistrano is abandoned in favor of capistrano/symfony since almost one year

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I misread it as Capistrano 2 being feature frozen and Capifony sticking to this version only.

Comment: You're welcome ! Have a good use of Capistrano. I don't want make some spam, but in the same way, I created a bundle that allow to configure capistrano interactively with pre-defined tasks and good configurations, for now it's not symfony3 ready but it could be a good thing to adapt it ! Do not hesitate to contribute, it's not complicated to make it evolves. https://github.com/chalasr/rchcapistranobundle . For moderators, If this comment is too much, I can remove it.